# Android : How to pause and resume runnable thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using a postDelayed runnable thread, I need to pause and resume that thread when I press a button. Please anyone help me on that.

This is my thread:

```
    protected void animation_music6() {
    music4.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
              music4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animationmusic4();
            holemusic4();

        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

I need to pause the thread when i press a button and resume from where i pause the thread. I have used to pause the thread is:

```
music4.removeCallbacks(runnable4);
```

How i can resume the thread? Can anyone please help me. Is there any way to pause and resume the thread? I am a new to the android, So please help me to do this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there is no pause `music4.removeCallbacks(runnable4);` stops the run. You need to start again. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: That means there is no pause for runnable thread?

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Nope.. no pause for thread :D

Comment: Maybe you can surround the content of your thread loop with a If condition (pause ? true or false)..

Answer (score 6):

I apologize for the poor formatting

```
 boolean isPaused = true;

 playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v) { 
        isPaused = !isPaused;
        if(isPaused) { 
            music4.removeCallbacks(runnable4);
        }
        else { 
            music4.postDelayed(runnable4, 100);
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue that I am confused about.
As taught here I'm using postDelayed() to have a Runnable start after a delay,
let´s say after 4 seconds. I want to implement a pause function so that if I pause, and at that point in time there for example is 2 seconds left until the runnable code was supposed to start, then when I later resume I want the delay to resume at the exact point in time where it became paused, so that the postDelayed operation will continue and will have the thread run 2 seconds after I resume. A kind of timer freeze()/unfreeze() operation.
Will I need to use timers to accomplish that ?

Comment: Comm enting on my own question some years later...
What I was working on was a 'scene player' that executes a timeline of events. And in the midst of all those scene events about to play out at any time I want to pause progress and be able to resume exactly where I paused.
The solution is to implement what's missing. Instead of a regular thread I create a class 'PauseThread' that adds the extra pause feature. Underneath the hood it works with regular threads and timers to accomplish the perceived experience of a 'pausable' thread, I won't go into the details but you may get some sense of it.

Comment: Hey, as  your comment, i am also trying to create a thread that could be paused/resumed. i have been searching for this for a long time. can you shed light on how you did that?